# Job shop scheduling: which solutions should I consider?

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling, resource-scheduling

Given a software company, where developers work in teams on a number
of different projects. Projects require a certain skill from assigned
developers. For my purposes, I want to keep it simple and limit this to one
skill, i.e. programming language. So some projects require Java, others require
C etc. Projects have a fixed duration, and each project should have two developers
assigned to it.

At any point in time, some projects are in progress and new projects come
in and need to be planned at some point in the future. I want to calculate a schedule of which developers should work on what project and when.

I'm not looking for the optimal solution (if that's even possible). I'm content
with a schedule a human manager could create.

I've read articles about Resource Constrained Scheduling Problems
and Assignment Problems, but I have very little formal CS training, and I'm
often lost in all the nuances in different variations of these problems.

I think my problem is a simpler variation of job shop scheduling where jobs are
projects, and developers are machines, so jobs require multiple machines at
the same time. There is only one precedent constraint, in that running projects
can't be aborted and so must be finished first.

From all the possible solutions I have read about, I'm inclined to use a
Genetic Algorithm, mainly because I've read people getting good results with
them and because I have used one a while ago for another project.
I've also read about good results with Linear Programming, but I know very little
about that.

Is a genetic algorithm a feasible solution for this type of problem? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: Are the tasks dependent on each other? (I.E. task 7 requires the completion of task 2 before it can begin). Are the tasks known in advance?

Comment: Do you mean the projects themselves when you say tasks? Projects are not dependent on each other. And at schedule creation time, all projects are known. For clarity, individual tasks in a project are not important in this problem. A project is considered finished when the predetermined duration has elapsed, as in SCRUM projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bipartite graph with developers on one side and needed project members on the other.  By "needed project members", I mean that if a project `P` needs 3 developers, you would add 3 nodes, perhaps named `P0`, `P1` and `P2`.

Draw an edge between a developer and a needed project member if that developer has all the skills required by that project.  Your problem then reduces to finding a [matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) within this graph; there are standard algorithms you could use to do this.

Comment: I'm going to look into this. Can this solution also handle the timing / scheduling part of my problem?

Comment: It wouldn't handle timing exactly, but if it found a matching in a graph involving all projects, then that matching would respect your scheduling constraints.  The problem is that it would be too restrictive: there would be graphs that have no matching, but would still have a possible scheduling (in which one dev does one project, and then later another.)  Per Doug's answer, you could greedily create the matching iteratively, one project at a time.  Then you could control the developer pool by excluding devs you know are busy.

Answer (score 0):

Using a genetic algorithm is a feasible approach, but it is very ambitious.

Start with a [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm).